# Stop Eclipse Console from blocking UI thread

Tags: java, eclipse

A test program of mine always made Eclipse Mars-2 hang forever.

After some testing (which wasn't easy having to find the line which kills Eclipse by binary search), I found out that applying `System.out.println` to a 350000 character String caused the problem.

Is there a way to handle accidentally long outputs for the console more gracefully, i.e. not blocking the whole of Eclipse forever?

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` often really causes such problems, because it's very slow to output lot's of data like this. That's why loggers are used.

However, if it isn't your code, so, yes, there is a way to limit the output to console:

Right click to the empty space inside Console view -> Preferences... -> In the Console submenu check "Limit console output" and set "Console buffer size" value